Tailwind CSS Styles Not Applying Automatically in React Project
I'm working on a React project and have integrated Tailwind CSS for styling. However, the Tailwind CSS styles do not apply automatically when I make changes to my CSS or component files. I have to manually run the following command to see the updates:
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/index.css -o ./src/junk/output.css --watch
Here are the steps I've taken to set up Tailwind CSS in my project:

Installed Tailwind CSS and dependencies:
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer

Initialized Tailwind CSS:
npx tailwindcss init -p

Configured tailwind.config.js (NOTE: most of the syntax here is for chadcn cli...):


/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  darkMode: ["class"],
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,jsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,jsx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,jsx}",
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: "2rem",
      screens: {
        "2xl": "1400px",
      },
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        border: "hsl(var(--border))",
        input: "hsl(var(--input))",
        ring: "hsl(var(--ring))",
        background: "hsl(var(--background))",
        foreground: "hsl(var(--foreground))",
        primary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--primary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--primary-foreground))",
        },
        secondary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--secondary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--secondary-foreground))",
        },
        destructive: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--destructive))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--destructive-foreground))",
        },
        muted: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--muted))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--muted-foreground))",
        },
        accent: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--accent))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--accent-foreground))",
        },
        popover: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--popover))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--popover-foreground))",
        },
        card: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--card))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--card-foreground))",
        },
      },
      borderRadius: {
        lg: "var(--radius)",
        md: "calc(var(--radius) - 2px)",
        sm: "calc(var(--radius) - 4px)",
      },
      keyframes: {
        "accordion-down": {
          from: { height: "0" },
          to: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
        },
        "accordion-up": {
          from: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
          to: { height: "0" },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        "accordion-down": "accordion-down 0.2s ease-out",
        "accordion-up": "accordion-up 0.2s ease-out",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss-animate")],
};


postcss.config:

    /** @type {import('postcss-load-config').Config} */
const config = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};

export default config;

Created src/index.css with the following content (again most of it is for chadcn):
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  :root {
    --background: 0 0% 100%;
    --foreground: 0 0% 3.9%;
    --card: 0 0% 100%;
    --card-foreground: 0 0% 3.9%;
    --popover: 0 0% 100%;
    --popover-foreground: 0 0% 3.9%;
    --primary: 0 0% 9%;
    --primary-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --secondary: 0 0% 96.1%;
    --secondary-foreground: 0 0% 9%;
    --muted: 0 0% 96.1%;
    --muted-foreground: 0 0% 45.1%;
    --accent: 0 0% 96.1%;
    --accent-foreground: 0 0% 9%;
    --destructive: 0 84.2% 60.2%;
    --destructive-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --border: 0 0% 89.8%;
    --input: 0 0% 89.8%;
    --ring: 0 0% 3.9%;
    --radius: 0.5rem;
    --chart-1: 12 76% 61%;
    --chart-2: 173 58% 39%;
    --chart-3: 197 37% 24%;
    --chart-4: 43 74% 66%;
    --chart-5: 27 87% 67%;
  }

  .dark {
    --background: 0 0% 3.9%;
    --foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --card: 0 0% 3.9%;
    --card-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --popover: 0 0% 3.9%;
    --popover-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --primary: 0 0% 98%;
    --primary-foreground: 0 0% 9%;
    --secondary: 0 0% 14.9%;
    --secondary-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --muted: 0 0% 14.9%;
    --muted-foreground: 0 0% 63.9%;
    --accent: 0 0% 14.9%;
    --accent-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --destructive: 0 62.8% 30.6%;
    --destructive-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --border: 0 0% 14.9%;
    --input: 0 0% 14.9%;
    --ring: 0 0% 83.1%;
    --chart-1: 220 70% 50%;
    --chart-2: 160 60% 45%;
    --chart-3: 30 80% 55%;
    --chart-4: 280 65% 60%;
    --chart-5: 340 75% 55%;
  }
}

and import './index.css
When I start the development server with npm start, the Tailwind CSS changes are not applied unless I manually run the npx tailwindcss command. I've also checked and ensured that the content paths in tailwind.config.js are correct.
What am I missing? How can I make Tailwind CSS changes apply automatically without manually running the npx tailwindcss command each time? Any help would be appreciated!
Deleting and reinstalling all the packages and messing up with the tailwind configuration.
BTW  is saw this in the documentation if its relevant:
react warning

Could you please provide your postcss.config.js file?

I use the default version. I added it above
